# Does AVAudioPlayer stream a file from disk, or does it load it into memory all at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I want to play very long audio files of up to an hour. AVAudioPlayer seems to be the easiest solution. But is it also efficient or does it load the whole file into memory before playing?

Comment: "But is it also efficient or does it load the whole file into memory before playing?" - the two don't have direct 1:1 correlation. Efficiency ain't streaming.

Answer (score -1):

Apple's doc for [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) say:

> An instance of the AVAudioPlayer class, called an audio player,
>   provides playback of audio data from a file or memory.
>
> Applerecommends that you use this class for audio playback unless you are
>   playing audio captured from a network stream or require very low I/O
>   latency.